# Folder AES Encryption

Tags: encryption, aes

I am new to this field and I watched many simulation of AES. I'm curious on how exactly AES encrypts/decrypts OS folders?

Comment: Depends on what encryption software you are using

Comment: can we take "Anvi Folder Locker" as an example? I am searching in the internet and cant find answers on how the folders encrypt/decrypt? So confused about this because when I watched some simulation of AES, it encrypts numbers/letters input and cipher it. I hope you get what I am saying.

Comment: You might be better off asking over at http://crypto.stackexchange.com as i assume your asking a mathematical question

Answer (score 1):

AES is a standard for encrypting/decrypting data. It doesn't specify how folders and files will be represented after encrypting them, so different crypto software may represent folders differently and is entirely up to the software you use to decide how to do it.

One method of how a crypto software will represent folders inside a single encrypted file would be a file achiever i.e. tarball format (.tar), it could also be combined with gzip to compress the archive before encrypting it.

I'm not saying crypto software does this, just that this is ONE method for how a crypto software 'could' represent files/folders if that what you're asking and has nothing to do with AES itself.

Comment: Do you have any sources that i can look up to? Like the one you said above.

Comment: Do you need to encrypt the folder as it is or encrypt content (files) inside a one particular folder?

Comment: The software do not care whats inside the folder. What I need is to encrypt the folder whatever the content of that folder.

Comment: Well for example, programs like 7Zip can create a file archive of the content say in 7z format (and compress them if you want) and encrypt them with AES. You can take a look at it on its official website, it's also open-source. Might be a useful program for you if that's what you want.